# Removing the time from a datetime function

Tags: python, pandas, list, datetime

```
solar["DATE"]= solar['DATE'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

display(solar)
```

I want to remove the time function from the DATE column. I only want the date, how do I get rid of it but keep the date?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G8Jg.png

The error I get is below:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: `solar['DATE'].dt.date`

Answer (score 0):

According to the error i think so you are using pandas dataframe and to edit the values you will have to use .apply() function.

```
You can do it via:
#IF the values are already a datetime object
solar['DATE'].apply(lambda d: d.date())

#ELSE IF dates are a string:
solar['DATE'].apply(lambda d: d.stftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Answer (score 0):

What I came up with is what follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime
date = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", periods=500, freq="H")
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({"date":date})
def removeDayTime(date):
  dateStr = str(date) # This line is just to change the timestamp format to str. You probably do not need this line to include in your code.
  dateWitoutTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateStr, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  return dateWitoutTime
dataframe["date"] = dataframe["date"].apply(removeDayTime)
dataframe.head()
```

Note that in order to have example data to work with, I have generated 500 periods of dates. You probably do not need to use my dataframe. So just use the rest of the code.

##### Output

|  | date |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2018-01-01 |
| 1 | 2018-01-01 |
| 2 | 2018-01-01 |
| 3 | 2018-01-01 |
| 4 | 2018-01-01 |